# Averaging Histograms

Tags: mean, histogram

I am currently running experiments which include measuring concentrations throughout an environment, producing a histogram as such:[image]

Which shows the percentage of positions which have oxygen concentrations between 0 and 10%, 10% and 20% etc.

I am running the experiment multiple times, and would like to know what is the proper way of "averaging" results or if the idea of averaging just doesn't make sense.

I can think of two options:

1) Taking the average value of each bin across all experiments (but then my percentages wouldn't add to 100%...)

2) Summing the values of each bin across all experiments, and calculating the percentage in terms of total samples across all bins across experiments.

Is any of the two options sensible?

Edits from comments:

Sample sizes could be different between experiments

Comment: Are your sample sizes unequal across multiple experiments?

Comment: I can't guarantee they're the same. It's an agent-based model so there could be different numbers of cells.

Comment: If you take the weighted average in (1), I believe it is the same with option (2).

Comment: Be careful not to fall into the XY-problem; Is a histogram the desired result or is there another underlying question you want to answer? If it is, why can't you concatenate all three experiments and make one histogram of their combined original data? If there is reason to assume the measurements within the three experiments are correlated, this seems like a clear example to me of something you should model with mixed model (using a random effect for experiment).